# IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL in Java 1.6, but working fine in 1.7 & 1.8

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Hi Im getting 400 in http response in 1.6, but works fine in 1.7 and 1.8

some one can help me on this.

Code:

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols","TLSv1,SSLv2Hello");   
String  urlParameters  = Constants.GRANT_TYPE+"&"+Constants.CLIENT_ID+"&"+Constants.CLIENT_SECRET+"&"+Constants.USER_NAME+"&"+Constants.PASSWORD;

        URL url;

        HttpURLConnection con = null;  
        try {
          //Create connection
            url = new URL(Constants.AUTH_URL);
        String s =  URLEncoder.encode(Constants.AUTH_URL);
          con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
            con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
              con.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters2);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(responseCode);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
```

getting error at con.getInputStream()

please help me on this.

Comment: It's likely that 1.6 - being 11 years old after all - doesn't have the certificate chain you need.  But without a stack trace you've left us to only guess.